# ISAPI_Rewrite3 IIS Module in Azure App Services PaaS

Tags: .htaccess, azure, azure-web-app-service, paas, isapi-rewrite

we have a legacy ASP.NET website that depends on the module ISAPI_Rewrite3 for URL rewriting. It uses a .htaccess file.

this was a necessity for URL rewriting before IIS7 which now features a built in URL Rewirite engine.

we want to migrate it to Azure PaaS App Services but can App Services cater for 3rd party modules such as this?

any help is most appriciated

JGilmartin

Answer (score 0):

With Azure App Services, you can't install 3rd party IIS modules if they are not listed on extensions list at `https://<yourappname>.scm.azurewebsites.net/SiteExtensions/#gallery`.

In this case, you'll need to translate `.htaccess` content to IIS `web.config` before you migrate. About how to do this, please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig).